# pgpool2 does not start

Tags: postgresql

after a successful installation of pgpool using the command `sudo apt-get install pgpool2` I am unable to start the service. The error message is this: 
[image: error message when starting pgpool]

I have given postgres all the necessary privileges on both pgpool.conf and pgpool.pid.

When I do `sudo service pgpool2 status` here is what I have got

[image]